# Why cant I connect phpmyadmin to html file?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

So I'm working on creating an ecommerce system and have successfully set up the main bits. My database is running with 2 tables so far, "Categories" and "Products".

Categories is successfully connected to my index.php file but products is not connecting. Basically, if I insert data to Categories from my html file, it will show up on PhpMyAdmin, but the same wouldn't work for products.

I will post below the code for the related files. I would REALLY appreciate some help on this as I've been stuck on this issue for days now! Thank you

If you would prefer for me to email you the whole folder please let me know

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<?php
include("includes/db.php");
?>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Inserting Product</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="limegreen">

  <form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table align="center" width="750px" border="2" bgcolor="white">

      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="7">
          <h2>Insert New Product Here</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Title:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Category:</b></td>
        <td>
          <select name="product_cat">
            <option>Select a Category</option>

            <?php
 $get_cats = "select * from categories";
 
 $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
 
 while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
 
  $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id']; 
  $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
  
   echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>"; 
    }
    
   
    ?>

          </select>


      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required/></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Quantity:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_quantity" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Description:</b></td>
        <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="40" rows="10" /></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="product_image" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords:</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert Product Now" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </form>

</body>

</html>enter code here


<?php

 if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
  
  //getting text data from fields
  $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
  $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
  $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
  $product_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'];
  $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
  $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
  
  //getting the image from the fields
  $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
  $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
  
  move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
  
  echo $insert_product = "insert into product (product_title,product_cat,product_price,product_quantity,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values ('$product_title','$product_cat','$product_price','$product_quantity','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";
  
  $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);
  
  if($insert_pro){
   
  echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted!')</script>";
  echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";
   
  }
  
 }


?>
```

Comment: // TO CONNECT DATABASE (seperate file) <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");

?>

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL Injection. Please use parameterized queries. This will also eliminate issues with quoting. When you say it "isn't connecting", I presume you mean that the row isn't inserted. Are you getting any error messages? If not, enable error display, or check the log file for errors.

Comment: Please check for errors returned from `mysqli_query()`. Please read this. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php